# JqGrid, change cell type from text to checkbox under condition

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a grid that's dependent on values of other values of the current row; I want to show a checkbox or an editbox.
I don't want to change the whole column. I searched for a long time, but it seems to be impossible.

Regards,
Dominik

Comment: you should use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) and define both `formatter` and `unformat` callback functions.

Comment: Hi Oleg, i found this today :
http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-Place-Controls-dynamically-in-each-Row-of-a-jQGrid-1013.php It worked, but i'll also look at your solution ! Many thanks for the quick response !

Comment: [The solution](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-Place-Controls-dynamically-in-each-Row-of-a-jQGrid-1013.php) is not good from performance point, but it's really important only in case of many rows in the grid. The usage of custom formatter is very easy, but I can't write the answer because your question don't contain enough information: which input data can have the column? which exact criteria for setting the checkbox and which for setting of editbox? should be both control be **disabled**? if the controls are not disabled, then what should be done on changing content of the controls.

Comment: Number of Rows will be up to 50, Number of columns up to 30. The hidden column "id" contains the type of row and a unique number, First visible column is a text. Depending on the value of the "id" at some rows all columns on the right are checkboxes, at other rows are textboxes which should contain only numbers. The grid is a tree, imagine a calendar with expandable text on the left and days of month on the right.